# Problems with localization

Tags: plugin-development, localization, translation

I'm creating a plugin and I've put:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'it_IT');
```

into `wp-config.php` file.

After plugin Name in the Header of the Plugin declaration:

```
* Text Domain: endpoint
* Domain Path: /languages/
```

For the load domain:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_load_textdomain' );

function myplugin_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'endpoint', false, dirname(  __FILE__  ) . '/languages/' ); 
}
```

In languages I created pot, po  and mo file with this names: `end-point.pot`, `end-point-it_IT.po` and `end-point-it_IT.mo`.

I switched to Italian but nothing is changed.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

1) Presuming you're running WordPress 4.x. The `WPLANG` constant does nothing. WordPress 3 and below defined the default language in `wp-config.php` but since WordPress 4 setting your site language is done via the General Settings page in your admin area. Go to *Settings > General* and scroll to the bottom where is says "Site Language" next to a dropdown list.

2) The argument `dirname(__FILE__).'/languages/'` is wrong as this should be a relative path.  Use `dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages/'`

Comment: Yeah I saw that via trace file created by xdebug. However Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made a mistake with dirname (**FILE**) . /languages/ and the fact that debuggin via load_plugin_textdomain I saw that it create the file name by the domaèn passed as argument to the function.

Thanks anyway.